# jQuery mouseenter and mouseleave events fire out of control

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, mouseevent

I'm using this piece of code to populate a div with the contents of a hovered element.

```
$('.gallery .thumbs a').hover(
  function(){
    var target = $(this);
    $('.hover-box').html(target.clone());
    var top = target.offset().top;
    var left = target.offset().left;
    $('.hover-box').css({'display':'block', 'top':top, 'left':left}); 
  },
  function(){
    $('.hover-box').hide();
  }
);
```

The problem is - what many seem to have had - that after adding the 'mouseleave' handler both the events start firing uncontrollably.

I know the bubbling issues related with mouseover/out but this seems to behave the same.

Anyone have an idea why this is happening?

EDIT:

Here's the deal on fiddle. Not the prettiest sight but function the same as my problem.
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FqLsg/6/)

Comment: You're probably popping up an element where the mouse pointer is, triggering the events multiple times. Set up a JSFiddle so we can see how it's supposed to work!

Comment: I agree with @adeneo.  Try changing your "top" and "left" variables to a new location (0,0 for example) and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your function fires and re-fires each `hover` and at the end of each `hover`, so any time you move the mouse it fires twice. What you want to do instead is fire it on `mouseenter` of `.thumbs a` and `mouseleave` of `.hover-box`, [**like this**](http://jsfiddle.net/FqLsg/10/)

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('.thumbs a').hover(

    function () {
        var target = $(this);
        jQuery('.hover-box').html(target.clone());
        var top = target.offset().top;
        var left = target.offset().left;
        jQuery('.hover-box').css({
            'display': 'block',
            'top': top,
            'left': left
        });
    });
    $('.hover-box').mouseleave(function() {
        $('.hover-box').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: The point your problem is the position ".hover-box" is right as the same as the '.thumbs a', so when ".hover-box" shows, it will trigger the "mouseleave" event of ".thumbs a"; however, when '.hover-box' hides, the 'mouseover' event of the '.thumbs a' is triggered again. So it's a kind of loop. That's why it is out of control.

Comment: @Sphinx Thank you for the better phrasing of the situation

Comment: Of course this is the problem. Thanks a lot for this enlightenment. I'll give this a go today at work, but I'm sure it's the correct answer.